# Altering the view of form only by clicking on the button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any code like, frmBallloon is shown in btnShow click event of the frmBase and again I want to show frmBase if user clicks on the btnShow of the frmBalloon then there is two copy of the frmBase.I want only one copy.Then how can I alter the form view by clicking on the button.

Comment: Do you mean to alter the form's content to represent the new data, instead of opening another form?

Comment: No if there is two forms then I want to alter the view of form1 and form2 one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

frmBase button click

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
this.Visible = false;
frm2.Show(this);
```

And here frmBalloon Button Click

```
if (this.Owner != null)
{
this.Visible = false;
this.Owner.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

Code for Form1

```
public Form2 f2;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f2 == null)
    {
        f2 = new Form2 {f1 = this};
        f2.Show();
    }
    else
        f2.Focus();
}
```

Code for Form2

```
public Form1 f1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f1 == null)
    {
        f1 = new Form1 {f = this};
        f1.Show();
    }
    else
        f1.Focus();
}
```